# Javascript integration using jQuery easing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, easing

I'm struggling to make this code work, basically I have this section of code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-easing.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

hidden = true;
$(".btn-slide").click(function () {
if(hidden == false) {

    $("#photodisplay").slideUp(1000, method, callback);
    $("#gallery").slideDown(1000, method, callback);
    hidden = true;
} else {
    $("#photodisplay").slideUp(1000, method, callback);
    $("#gallery").slideDown(1000, method, callback);
    hidden = false;
}
});
});
</script>
```

This when written normally in Javascript using the slideUp and 'slow' works fine but I just want to include the easing as at the moment it's a bit static. 
How can I adjust this so that the jQuery works? Any help would be great, thanks in advance,

Sofi

Comment: Where do you define `method`? Or maybe I don't understand -- What's going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean but slideUp and slideDown have three parameters.

```
.slideUp( [duration,] [easing,] [callback] )
```

So what you can do is:

```
$('#photodisplay').slideUp(1000, "linear", callback);

function callback() {
    alert("The photodisplay finished the slideup");
}
```

And instead of using the hidden variable you could also check whether or not the selector is visible using:

```
$('#photodisplay').is(':hidden')
```

Comment: Yeah, thing is it won't function at all ie. the slides don't work if the parameters are like this? If I set the parameter to 'slow' it works fine. 

but using the parameters you've specified for the animation doesn't seem to be working? :/

Comment: Mmmh, it should work. But anyway, in most cases you won't need the [easing] and [callback] parameters. I think in your case $('#photodisplay').slideUp(1000); will suffice.